# SAS absorb function in R

Tags: r, glm, lm

I have a dataset (sample columns and data included below) for which I run a regression in SAS using the following:

```
proc glm data = dataset;
model units = price;
by category;
absorb store;
run;
```

The dataset has mulitple categories and multiple stores for each category.  The coefficient I get from SAS differs from the coefficient I get when I run a regression in R using:

```
lm(units~ price, data=data)
```

I understand that the two models are different.  But how can I replicate the SAS model that uses absorb and runs the model by category in R?

```
Date          Store     Category    units           price
05/29/15    1500261     Drinks      -1.579668674    1.455073877
05/29/15    1500314     Drinks      -1.356171009    1.429736919
05/29/15    1500361     Drinks      -1.033295892    1.359770698
```

Comment: Can you post your results and a link to some dummy data?

Comment: Most of us don't have an SAS license (we have R after all). Show the output and explain what the SAS code does.

Comment: according to the [sas docs](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63033/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_glm_sect032.htm), you don't need the absorb statement, so I suppose you can use the other way and then translate into r

Comment: also @Joe I am not sure why you always insist on removing the sas tag from these types of questions, it is very counterproductive. obviously you or another sas expert may know the answer to this (or what absorb is doing) without going through the docs like I just did. But by removing the tags, the sas programmers will never see this question, so what is your motivation for doing this every single time?

Comment: [tag:sas] is appropriate for a question about SAS.  These are questions about R.  By convention, straight code replication should not be tagged with the original language's tag.  If the question is "What does SAS do", then it's welcome to have [tag:sas] - but that's not what this question asks.

Comment: @rawr - maybe this should be brought up on Meta?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a relatively small number of stores then just use `lm(units~ price+factor(stores), data=data)`

The "by category" statement in SAS can be implemented by each category in a subset argument `lm(units~ price+factor(stores), data=data, subset=category=="Drinks")`. Each category has to be inserted consecutively in the subset argument.

If you have many stores:

The absorb statement in SAS is the equivalent to the fixed effects approach which is implemented in the `plm` function. First, the dataset has to be organized with stores and date in the first and second column of your dataset and then sorted accordingly to make this procedure run:

```
datanew<-data[order(data$stores,data$Date),]
```

And then use:

```
library(plm)
plm(units~ price, data=datanew, subset=category=="Drinks",
effect="individual",model="within",index=c("stores","date"))
```

Now you can even further control for time-periods if you change "individual" to "twoways".